# Time complexity of recursive factorization function inside for loop

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Here's my algorithm in pseudocode: What it does is it returns a list of prime numbers that gives the factorization of number n. For example, 75 = 3 * 5 * 5

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> FACTORISATION(int n) {
    if (PRIME(n)) {
        // return a one-element array
        return new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(n));
    } else {
        // find a prime divisor, p
        for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
                newList.add(i);
                newList.addAll(FACTORISATION(n/i));
                return newList;
            }
        }
    }
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

According to me, time complexity can be calculated as:-

```
T(n) = 2 + T(n-1/p) + T(n-2/p) +...
T(n) = nT(n-1/p)
T(n) = O(n!)
```

The `PRIME(n)` method has a complexity of `O(n)`

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated. First, please correct the bug in your code, it should be `i <= Math.sqrt(n);` instead of `i < Math.sqrt(n);`.

Let's start with the unique representation of integer as a product of powers of its prime divisors:

n = p<sub>1</sub><sup>a<sub>1</sub></sup> p<sub>2</sub><sup>a<sub>2</sub></sup> p<sub>3</sub><sup>a<sub>3</sub></sup>...p<sub>k</sub><sup>a<sub>k</sub></sup>

(for example, 120 = 2<sup>3</sup> 3<sup>1</sup> 5<sup>1</sup>). How many times would `for` loop in your code be executed for input `n` (not counting recursive sub-calls)? Exactly `i-1` times, where `i` is the smallest prime divisor of `n`. That's because when first such `i` is found, loop terminates (`return newList;` statement). If `n` is itself a prime, `for` loop won't be executed at all because `if (PRIME(n))` will return true.

For which input arguments would `FACTORISATION(int n)` be called (recursively)? Pay attention, it will be called for n, and then for

n/p<sub>1</sub>,

n/p<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>,

..

n/p<sub>1</sub><sup>a<sub>1</sub></sup>,

n/p<sub>1</sub><sup>a<sub>1</sub></sup>p<sub>2</sub>,

n/p<sub>1</sub><sup>a<sub>1</sub></sup>p<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>,

..

n /p<sub>1</sub><sup>a<sub>1</sub></sup>p<sub>2</sub><sup>a<sub>2</sub></sup>,

..

n/p<sub>1</sub><sup>a<sub>1</sub></sup> p<sub>2</sub><sup>a<sub>2</sub></sup> p<sub>3</sub><sup>a<sub>3</sub></sup>...p<sub>k</sub>,

..

n/p<sub>1</sub><sup>a<sub>1</sub></sup> p<sub>2</sub><sup>a<sub>2</sub></sup> p<sub>3</sub><sup>a<sub>3</sub></sup>...p<sub>k</sub><sup>a<sub>k</sub>-1</sup>.

That was the hardest part - if you understood this, you're done :) Now just sum up the running time that comes from testing `PRIME(n)` and running time that comes from executing `for` loop. The latter contributes in total with (p<sub>1</sub> - 1)a<sub>1</sub> + (p<sub>2</sub> - 1)a<sub>2</sub> + .. + (p<sub>k</sub> - 1)a<sub>k</sub>, while first part contributes with n + n/p<sub>1</sub> + n/p<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + ... + n/p<sub>1</sub><sup>a<sub>1</sub></sup> p<sub>2</sub><sup>a<sub>2</sub></sup> p<sub>3</sub><sup>a<sub>3</sub></sup>...p<sub>k</sub><sup>a<sub>k</sub>-1</sup>. It's impossible to evaluate the asymptotic complexity of this sum without seriously digging into number theory, but it's much better than `O(n!)` (for the upper bound for sum of divisors, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819908/upper-bound-for-the-difference-between-number-of-divisors-and-sum-of-divisors-fu)).